# coger double ubicado dentro de un String

Tags: java

tengo una pregunta un poco simple pero que no se como arreglarlo:

Si tengo un string tipo:

```
String s = "hola0.2adios";
```

¿Cómo podría coger el 0.2  que está entre **hola** y **adios** para convertirlo en un double de manera simple?

Comment: Tienes que usar Regex (expresiones regulares) para separar los caracteres de alfabéticos y quedarte con los numéricos

Comment: ¿El 0.2 estará en la misma posición? Debes especificar ese detalle en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la forma más sencilla de hacerlo es con expresiones regulares..

```
String s = "hola0.2adios";
String foo = "";
for(char a : s.toCharArray()){
    if(Pattern.matches("\\d*\\.*-*",a+""))
        foo = foo + a;
}

System.out.println("foo: "+Double.parseDouble(foo));
```

**output**

```
foo: 0.2
```